# Memory leak when setting texture = new Texture2D(...)

Tags: c#, performance, xna, garbage-collection, xna-4.0

I have the following code as part of a game:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        terrainSprite.Draw(spriteBatch);

        if (resourceMap.pixels.IsDisposed == false)
        {
            resources.Draw(spriteBatch, spriteFont);
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);

       //Disposes the texture here:
        resources.pixels.Dispose();
    }

    //In the resources class
    public void Update()
    {       
        //gD = graphics device
        pixels = new Texture2D(gD, 800, 353);

        //big update method
        //manipulate the pixels texture
    }
```

When I open task manager and look at the resource monitor, the memory usage for 'myGame.exe' is constantly going up by about 8 KB (I realize this is small, but my game holds a LOT of data, so saving every bit I can is important, and it builds up fairly quickly). This is after all other code is commented out except for what is shown here. Then, when I comment out the code: "pixels = new Texture2D(gD, 800, 353);", the memory usage stays constant. I also tried GC.Collect(), but no dice.

Is there anything else I can do to try and stop it? (Sorry, getting rid of the code is not an option :p, renewing the texture is much faster than any other method I've come across to make the texture go blank)

Comment: Hard to tell by the code, but are you absolutely sure that you have a memory leak? Its quiet normal that the memory goes up. A Dispose is no c++ delete, The Garbage collector will decide when to actually free space, until then it will just pile up which is fine. So don't trust the taskmanager, and don't trust Collect, which is a request to the GC not a a command. Use a real memory leak finder.

Comment: Well, it only occurs when that line of code is not commented out, otherwise the memory usage does stay constant. In other words, I have no idea what it really is. :p

Comment: @dowhilefor I think you are correct, it will decide when to clear up the data by itself when it wants to, however, if this extraneous data stacks on top of the rest before it clears, it throws an OOM Exception earlier than it normally would. I might be stuck where I am, and I'll just have to create a maximum number of instances for the other objects... Which basically means the game won't be as great as it could be :c

Comment: Is the Texture2D object have any unmanaged resources that are not being disposed / released properly?  When you set the reference for pixels to a new object - the old object may be hanging around because something else has a reference to it.  I would especially look at an events you may have wired up - as those will need to be unwired manually.

Comment: I would think that .Dispose() would take care of that, I mean that is the point isn't it? But anyway, I literally commented out every part of the code except for those two or three necessary lines, and the problem persists. I never load anything into content manager either, the texture is only set manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your `Game` configuration and really, many other factors, such as how slow everything is running, etc., `Update` and `Draw` are not perfectly synchronous with each other and are *not guaranteed* to be run in the following fashion:

```
Update
Draw
Update
Draw
Update
Draw
Update
Draw
....
```

Therefore, since you're `Dispose`ing in one and creating a *brand new one* in the other, something like this can definitely happen:

```
Update: create new
Update: create new //PREVIOUS ONE LEAKED!
Draw: disposes only current
Update: create new
Update: create new //AGAIN LEAK
Draw: disposes only current
...
```

Thus, do not `Dispose` separately in this fashion; `Dispose` one time for each new one created, no matter what.

I should also add on that textures, along with some other XNA classes (sound and music, and `Effect`s, to name a few) are *unmanaged* resources, meaning the GC does not see them at all. You must call `Dispose` on these.

As Andrew points out in his comment, the best way to avoid these pitfalls is not to recreate textures so often - simply reuse the same one and modify it as you see fit.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the best solution to the OP's problem is to simply reuse the texture object - rather than recreating it each frame. I was about to answer saying "CLR Profiler", because I didn't spot the unmanaged memory leak - nicely spotted.

Comment: Good call - I was actually going to comment "why are you creating a new texture each frame?" before spotting it myself :)

Comment: Well yeah, thats the best solution _to avoid the leak_ (in relation to the comments, not the accepted answer), but it is not getting rid of it. Unfortunately, the nature of my game requires a lot of pixel manipulation, and starting off with a blank texture each update is necessary. (In my research I have found that using new is the fastest way to clear the texture, so far) Unless you would like to help out on my other post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047489/optimal-way-to-set-pixel-data

Comment: @Colton I'll put some suggestions over on that question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Texture2D are not fully handled by the garbage collector.

So when you stop using it (when reusing a variable referencing it, like here, or during the OnDestroy callback), you have to manually destroy the texture. Here :

```
if(pixels != null) {
  Destroy(pixels);
}
pixels = new Texture2D(gD, 800, 353);
```